# Searching for a value in pyrebase

Tags: python, database, firebase, raspberry-pi, pyrebase

[image: firebase]

I have check pyrebase and i want to search for the IDNumber of each user.

i have tried using

```
db.child("Users").order_by_child("IDNumber").equal_to(2011445392).get()
```

But it gave me an error related to index not defined.
Is there a way to search for IDNumber similar to SQL?

Comment: i can't do that because i will not know if 'Morty' will have the id number 2011445392 or someone else. so i would be using the id number for searching users instead of names.

Comment: You are right, read [guide/indexing-data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct. The error about index not defined occurs because you haven't set any rule on `IDNumber`.

You need to configure rules on your indexes like this :

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      ".indexOn": ["IDNumber"]
    }
  }
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-defining-indexes